# Is it possible to leave and re-enter the USA while in an H1B post-employment grace period?

Tags: usa, h1-visa

During the 60 day period following termination of employment, is it possible to re-enter the USA if a person shows either their valid visa stamp OR their valid visa stamp and I-797 transfer approval notice at the border?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot enter in H-1B status during your 60-day grace period because the grace period expires along with your nonimmigrant status as soon as you leave the US.

If you have an approved petition to begin work for another employer, you can enter as many as ten days before the beginning of the petition's period of validity or ten days after the end of its validity under [8 CFR 214.1(l)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/214.1#l).